# Cannot connect to a database in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I created a simple form in HTML to add the details of student. It contains text fields foe first name, last name, age, phone and email. And i created a database in wamp phpmyadmin and created a table named stud with fields fname, lname, age, phone, email and my PHP code to add the data from the form to table stud is given below

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="";
$password="";
$db_name="student";


$tbl_name="stud"; 
$connect=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($connect,$db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
$fname=$_POST['fname'];    
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(fname, lname, age, phone, email)VALUES('$fname', '$lname' ,'$age', '$phone',  `'$email')";`
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='student.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}
else { 
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
<?php

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

when I run this code in a browser it shows "cannot connect DB".
But when i created a table named stud in test database it worked.
Please help me to find a way to connect to my stud table in student database in wamp.

Comment: Instead of using your own error message text (which jsut tells you "FAIL" and no real feedback), echo out the actual system provided error message - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: it looks kike you're trying to connect to "student" instead of "stud", $db_name="student" should be $db_name="stud". Make sure both names are the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use below

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name")or die("Error in database connection");
```

OR

Check your username beacause default username in wamp is

> root

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. use
`mysqli_select_db($db_name, $con)` instead of
`mysqli_select_db($con, $db_name)`